# Printing random cards (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am writing a program to deal a deck of cards. I need them to be dealt at random. I'm just not sure to print them randomly.
This is the code I have so far..

```
import random


def create_deck():
    for i in range(10):
        pip = random.choice(PIPS)
        suit = random.choice(SUITS)
        card = (pip, suit)


def deal_deck(DECK):
    for pip in PIPS:
        for suit in SUITS:
            print(pip + suit,end=" ")
        print()

CLUB = "\u2663"
HEART = "\u2665"
DIAMOND = "\u2666"
SPADE = "\u2660"

PIPS = ("A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K")
SUITS = (CLUB, SPADE, DIAMOND, HEART)
DECK= []

create_deck
deal_deck(DECK)
```

Comment: Put all 52 cards in a list and then `shuffle` it.

Comment: Have you considered making a class for the Cards instead of using a tuple?

Comment: This is actually an assignment and I've been instructed to use tuples, and we haven't covered classes yet.

Comment: @H.Soto that's fine. I was just asking. You don't need to. It's just a little more Object Oriented to use a class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to product and shuffle the cards.

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle 
all_cards = list(product(PIPS, SUITES))

shuffle(all_cards)

just_10_cards = all_cards[:10]
for p, suite in just_10_cards:
    print(p, suite, end='')
print()
```